# AJAX: display a random line every minute

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I have [a PHP-script](http://preferans.de/hint.php) displaying random text:

```
<?php

$quotes = array(
        'quote 1',
        'quote 2',
        'quote 3',
        'quote 4',
        'quote 5',
);

$i = array_rand($quotes);

header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
print($quotes[$i]);

?>
```

How could I call it every minute to display a new quote (Russian text in UTF8 encoding) at my web page (which itself is [an iframe app](http://apps.facebook.com/video-preferans/) at Facebook)?

Do I need to use jQuery here or is there a lighter solution, working in the usual browsers?

I don't have any AJAX experience yet.

**UPDATE:**

As suggested by Uku Loskit below, I've added the following snippet and it works well. Can anybody please show me how to fade the new quote in with fadeIn()?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
        setTimeout( function() {
                $.get("/hint.php", function(data) {
                        $("#hint").html(data);
                });
        }, 5*60*1000 );
});
</script>
```

Thank you!
Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) method.

I'd say there's nothing heavy about using jQuery (especially the minified version) "just for AJAX", because it provides a cross-browser compatible solution and is much easier to program.

example:

```
function getNewQuotes() {
   $.get("random_quotes.php", function(data) {
       // set the response from random_quotes.php to this div
       $("#quotesDiv").html(data);
   }); 
}

// 60000 milliseconds = 60 seconds = 1 minute
var t=setTimeout("getNewQuotes()", 60000);
```

As for your question of mixing "non-JQuery and Javascript", there's no jQuery function for this that I know of, all-in-all jQuery is still Javascript and relying on jQuery specific code all the time isn't necessary, but would be only be useful for consistency.

Edit:

```
$(function() {
            setTimeout( function() {
                    $.get("/hint.php", function(data) {
                            // first hide, then insert contents
                            $("#hint").hide();
                            $("#hint").html(data);
                            // you can probably chain this together into one command as well
                            $("#hint").fadeIn("slow");

                    });
            }, 5*60*1000 );
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand how to call setTimeout, but how do I do the AJAX call to the quote.php?

Comment: Thank you, this works and I've updated the question. Can you please help me with the fadeIn() as the final touch? :-)

Comment: Thanks and I've ended up using setInterval.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jquery, but its easier like that. Just pick up from the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
Basic example of how to get it once:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "yourFileName.php",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(result){
    $('#someDiv').html('result');
  }
});
```

then add the javascript code to do this periodically. I'm sure you could find something nifty from the jquery thingymabob too :)

Comment: jQuery.ajax() doesn't have any "timer" argument, how could I enforce it being called every minute please?

Comment: use the setTimer for instance that @uku mentioned?

Comment: And what format/data should the script called by jQuery.ajax() print? Should it be text/plain or text/html? And should I print the <html> and <body> or just <p>my quote</p>?

Comment: Nanne, wouldn't that be a mix of jQuery with non-jQuery? Is there maybe a jQuery way for calling jQuery.ajax() periodically?

Comment: Also I'm confused by context: document.body - will that replace the complete web page?

Comment: There's no problem: keep in mind that jquery is a javascript library: its a batch of javascript functions to make your life easier, but it's still javascript. So if there is a fucntion in javascript that does the job, there's no need for jquery to even have a function to support it, but if it did there's no special need to not-use the normal one...

Comment: And just ignore the context, you don't need it. remove it if you want. Please, read the manual I linked